# sum google sheet and break line in different date

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, sumifs

I want to sum in a column but this sum need to break if is a different day

here a small example [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1idhCdboOMub2Oqmo_yhuaASIdWoZxkrTjnSLIHuj9qs/edit?usp=sharing)
Found this but formula `'=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A)),1,Sheet1!B2:B)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You mean something like this ?

```
={"Total"; ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),if(match(A2:A, A2:A, 0)=row(A2:A)-1,sumif(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B),),))}
```

[image]

Comment: if this just one day doesn't sum

Comment: Hi, based on Eric's post I changed the formula. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

JPV, I'm wondering if your solution would only work if there were exactly two entries per date.

My suggestion (in C2):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)="","",IF(A3:A=INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1),"",VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1),QUERY(A2:B,"Select A, SUM(B) Where A Is Not Null Group By A Order By A Desc"),2,FALSE))))
```

Comment: Eric, updated my formula so that the total per day now appears in the first row of the unique date. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select A,sum(B) where B is not null group by A"), 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]